Adding string values that have been formatted into currencies
I have a problem with adding values in my program. I'm making a food ordering program. A user picks, let's say pizza. That pizza costs £5. The user can add toppings to it like extra cheese for 80p, getting added to the pizza cost thus costing £5.80. These prices use the currency format, which formats a string value to a currency automatically and I can't really int.parse it. Here's the code for it:
namespace JustNom.Logic
{
    internal class DisplayMenu : MenuItem
    {
        private Menu _menu;

        private IEnumerable<Pizza> _pizza;

        private IEnumerable<Burger> _burger;

        private IEnumerable<Garnish> _garnish;

        private IEnumerable<Topping> _topping;

        //Creates the DisplayMenu constructor. 
        public DisplayMenu(Menu menu, IEnumerable<Pizza> pizzas, IEnumerable<Burger> burgers, IEnumerable<Garnish> garnishes, IEnumerable<Topping> toppings)
        {
            _menu = menu;
            _pizza = pizzas;
            _burger = burgers;
            _garnish = garnishes;
            _topping = toppings;
        }

        //Creates the menu text for the menu. 
        public override string MenuText()
        {
            return "\nAdd food to your order.";
        }

        //Creates the menu that displays the whole menu for the user. 
        public override void Select()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{MenuText()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            int i = 1;
            int price = 0;
            string moneyFormat = (price / 100m).ToString("C2");

            //IEnumerable<FoodItems> items = _pizza.Concat<FoodItems>(_burger);
            var items = _pizza.Cast<FoodItems>().Concat(_burger.Cast<FoodItems>()).ToList();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{i}. {item}");
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            int selectedIndex = ConsoleHelpers.GetIntegerInRange(1, items.Count, MenuText()) - 1;

            var selectedItem = items.ElementAt(selectedIndex);
            HandleSelection(selectedItem);

            void HandleSelection(FoodItems selectedItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\n{selectedItem}");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{Environment.NewLine}");
                List<string> currentToppings = null;
                if (selectedItem is Pizza pizza)
                {
                    currentToppings = pizza.GetToppings();
                }
                else if (selectedItem is Burger burger)
                {
                    currentToppings = burger.GetGarnishes();
                }

                if (currentToppings != null)
                {
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (var topping in currentToppings)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Remove {topping}");
                        i++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable toppings to add.");
                    foreach (var topping in _topping)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Add {topping}");
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                //Removes the topping/garnish that the user picks. 
                while (true)
                {
                    int toppingIndex = ConsoleHelpers.GetIntegerInRange(0, currentToppings.Count + _topping.Count(), "Select an action (0 to finish):") - 1;
                    if (toppingIndex == -1) break;

                    if (toppingIndex < currentToppings.Count)
                    {
                        string toppingToRemove = currentToppings.ElementAt(toppingIndex);
                        if (selectedItem is Pizza pizza1)
                        {
                            pizza1.RemoveTopping(toppingToRemove);
                        }
                        else if (selectedItem is Burger burger1)
                        {
                            burger1.RemoveGarnish(toppingToRemove);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine($"\nRemoved {toppingToRemove}");

                        Console.WriteLine($"\n{selectedItem}\nNo {toppingToRemove}\n");
                        if (currentToppings != null)
                        {
                            int i = 1;
                            foreach (var topping in currentToppings)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Remove {topping}");
                                i++;
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable toppings to add.");
                            foreach (var topping in _topping)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Add {topping}");
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Topping toppingToAdd = _topping.ElementAt(toppingIndex - currentToppings.Count);
                        if (selectedItem is Pizza pizza1)
                        {
                            pizza1.AddTopping(toppingToAdd.Name);
                            pizza1.Price += toppingToAdd.Price;
                        }
                        else if (selectedItem is Burger burger)
                        {
                            burger.AddGarnish(toppingToAdd.Name);
                            burger.Price += toppingToAdd.Price;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine($"\nAdded {toppingToAdd.Name}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"\n{selectedItem}\nExtra {toppingToAdd.Name} {toppingToAdd.Price}\n");
                        if (currentToppings != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var topping in currentToppings)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Remove {topping}");
                                i++;
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("\nAvailable toppings to add.");
                            foreach (var topping in _topping)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{i}. Add {topping}");
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Menus";
                    string fileName = "menu.txt";

                    SaveMenuToFile(fileName, directory);
                }

            }

        }
        private void SaveMenuToFile(string fileName, string directory)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);

            // Use StreamWriter to write to the file
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(filePath);
                sb.AppendLine("\nName: JustNom FastFood");

                // Toppings
                sb.Append("Toppings: [");
                sb.Append(string.Join(", ", _topping.Select(t => $"<{t.Name},{t.Price}>")));
                sb.AppendLine("]");

                // Garnishes
                sb.Append("Garnishes: [");
                sb.Append(string.Join(", ", _garnish.Select(g => $"<{g.Name},{g.Price}>")));
                sb.AppendLine("]");

                // Pizzas
                foreach (var pizza in _pizza)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"Pizza:< Name:{pizza.Name},Toppings: [{string.Join(", ", pizza.GetToppings())}],Price: {pizza.Price} >");
                }

                // Burgers
                foreach (var burger in _burger)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"Burger:< Name:{burger.Name}, Garnishes:[{string.Join(", ", burger.GetGarnishes())}],Price: {burger.Price} >");
                }

                // Write the string to the file
                writer.Write(sb.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Menu saved to {fileName}");
        }
    }
}

I have code that in theory is supposed to add the values together, instead it makes something like '£5.00£0.80'.
int.parse the string values, however they use the currency format.

Don't store the price as a formatted value, instead store it as an int (if that makes sense for you) and format it when you use it.

i didn't think of that. I'll convert my price to int and format it at the end when the value needs outputting to the console.

Why store price as int, when you yourself give an example of £5.80? That looks decimal to me.

What I recommend to do is creating an extension method for string class. This method will iterate through the price string character by character and ignore none-numeric values. As an example, take a look at the code below:
internal static class StringExtension
{
    public static decimal ExtractNumber(this string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.' )
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        return decimal.Parse( sb.ToString() );
    }
}

Now, you can use the extension method above to safely extract numbers from price strings like the following:
string price1 = "$345.23";
string price2 = "£5.80";

decimal p1 = price1.ExtractNumber(); //p1 value will be 345.23
decimal p2 = price2.ExtractNumber(); //p2 value will be 5.80

